# When is a formula preserved under taking factors in a reduced product or the stalk in a Boolean product?

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

I want to know if there is a nice characterization of when a formula is preserved under taking reduced factors.

We say that a formula $\phi$ is closed under taking reduced factors if whenever $I$ is a set, $Z$ is a filter on $I$ and $\prod_{i\in I}A_{i}/Z\models\phi([(a_{i,1})_{i\in I}],...,[(a_{i,n})_{i\in I}])$, then $\{i\in I|A_{i}\models\phi(a_{i,1},...,a_{i,n})\}\in Z$. Is there a good characterization of which formulas are preserved under taking reduced factors?

We say that a formula $\phi$ is closed under taking Boolean product stalks if whenever

1. $X$ is a compact zero-dimensional space
2. $A_{x}$ is a structure for each $x\in X$
3. $A\subseteq\prod_{x\in X}A_{x}$ is a subalgebra where $\pi_{x}[A]=A_{x}$ whenever $\pi_{x}:\prod_{x\in X}A_{x}\rightarrow A_{x}$ is the projection.
4. whenever $f_{1},...,f_{n}\in A$ and $(C_{1},...,C_{n})$ is a partition of $X$ into clopen sets, then $f_{1}|_{C_{1}}\cup...\cup f_{n}|_{C_{n}}\in A$
5. whenever $\phi$ is a formula and $f_{1},...,f_{n}\in A$, then
   $\{x\in X|A_{x}\models\phi(f_{1}(x),...,f_{n}(x))\}$ is a clopen subset of $X$,

then whenever $A\models\phi(f_{1},...,f_{n})$, then $A_{x}\models\phi(f_{1}(x),...,f_{n}(x))$ for each $x\in X$.

Is there a characterization of the formulas closed under taking Boolean product stalks? Are the formulas closed under taking Boolean product stalks precisely the formulas closed under taking reduced factors?

$\textbf{Background}$

A formula of the form $A_{1}\wedge...\wedge A_{n}\rightarrow B$ or of the form $(\neg A_{1})\vee...\vee(\neg A_{n})$ where $A_{1},...,A_{n},B$ are atomic is said to be a basic Horn formula. A formula of the form $Q_{1}x_{1}...Q_{n}x_{n}(\phi_{1}\wedge...\wedge\phi_{n})$ where $Q_{1},...,Q_{n}$ are quantifiers and $\phi_{1},...,\phi_{n}$ are basic horn formulae is said to be a Horn formula. It is a standard result that a formula is equivalent to a Horn formula if and only if whenever $A_{i}\models\phi(a_{1,i},...,a_{n,i})$ for $i\in I$ and $Z$ is a filter on $I$, then $\prod_{i\in I}A_{i}/Z\models\phi([(a_{1,i})_{i\in I}],...,[(a_{n,i})_{i\in I}])$.

It is an exercise in Chang and Keisler that every positive sentence is preserved under taking reduced factors, but not every sentence preserved under reduced factors is a positive sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Only a sketchy partial answer.)

The family of *factorable formulas*, is the smallest set $F$ of formulas
containing every atomic formula that is closed under conjunction,
existential and universal quantification, and the following rule:

> if $\alpha(\vec x),\beta(\vec x, \vec y), \gamma(\vec x, \vec y)\in
> F$ and $\models\forall \vec x \bigl(\alpha(\vec x) \rightarrow \exists \vec y
>   \beta(\vec x, \vec y)\bigr)$ then $\forall \vec y   \bigl( \beta(\vec x,
>   \vec y) \rightarrow  \gamma(\vec x, \vec y)\bigr) \in F.$

It is easy to see that these formulas are preserved under direct factors **and** direct products. I was told that these formulas are preserved by reduced products and factors, though I didn't checked this. The place I found this is R. Willard, *Varieties Having Boolean Factor Congruences*, J. Algebra **132** (1990) 130--153, where a slight variant (relative to a class of models) is defined.

These are intimately related to *$h$-formulas*, defined by the simpler scheme

> 1. atomic formulas are $h$-formulas;
> 2. if $A$, $B$ are $h$-formulas and $x$ is a variable, then
>      $(A\wedge B)$ and $(\exists xA\wedge\forall x(A\rightarrow B))$
>      are $h$-formulas.

(I was informed about this family of formulas by an anonymous referee, and he cited the paper E. A. Palyutin, *Categorical Horn classes, I.*, Algebra and Logic **19** (1980) 377--400, but I have no access to it.)

Still in the *sketchy & partial* vein, I didn't checked if they are actually the same fam

Finally, although not directly related, the paper by Hugo Volger, *Preservation Theorems for Limits of Structures and Global Sections of Sheaves of Structures*, Math. Z. **166**, 27--53 (1979), might be relevant here. He gives a partial solution to the problem of characterizing sentences preserved by Boolean products.